# Observable depende de otro Observable Angular

Tags: angular, observable

distinguida comunidad, después de días de tratar de hallar la solución vengo a pedir su ayuda. Soy nuevo en esto, estoy intentando armar un objeto donde recupero información de firestore, pero para realizar las consultas dependo de consultas anteriores. Para ello tengo dos funciones que son observables y me devuelven los valores de la base de datos. Pero cuando intento armar el objeto el resultado es que obtengo observables dentro del objeto. Espero me puedan ayudar. Gracias

```
this.orgSvc.getAllOrganizaciones().pipe(
        map(actions =>
          actions.map(a => {
            let childrenC = this.orgSvc.getAllDivisiones(a.id).pipe(
              map(actions =>
                actions.map(b => {
                  return { name: b.nombrecomercial, division: b.rubro, id: b.id };
                })
              )
            );
            return { name: a.nombreclave, division: a.rubro, id: a.id, children: childrenC };
          })
        )
      );
```

También he intentado con el siguiente código, pero no se como esperar que se complete el código para poder usar los resultados:

```
this.orgSvc.getAllOrganizaciones().subscribe(r => {
      r.forEach(item => {
        let childrenC = [];
        this.orgSvc.getAllDivisiones(item.id).subscribe( g => {
          g.forEach(item => {
            childrenC.push({ name: item.nombrecomercial, division: item.rubro, id: item.id })
          });
        });
        this.organizacionData.push({ name: item.nombreclave, division: item.rubro, id: item.id, children: childrenC });
      });

    });
```

Comment: this.organizacionData.push tienes que ponerlo antes de cerrar "});" de la g del subscribe e inmediatamente después del "});" del forEach.

Comment: Te modifiqué el post, te faltaba ;

Comment: amigo, muchas gracias lo solucione con lo que me indicaste lineas arriba de el segundo codigo.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que ir concatenando las llamadas http, hasta que no termine una, que no se ejecute la siguiente.

Yo uso un archivo.ts diferente para realizar las llamadas http y no tenerlo todo en el mismo archivo.

```
import { DataService } from '../data.service'; // Importas el archivo externo.

public params: any; 
public params2: any;

constructor(private service: DataService) { }

public obtenerValores = function(id: string) {
  this.service.getAllDivisiones(id).subscribe(
            data => {
                 this.params =  data; // --> datos de la 1º llamada
                 this.service.get....(params.algo).subscribe(
                  data2=> {
                  this.params2 =  data2; // --> datos de la 2º llamada
                  // Cuando hayas terminado de hacer llamadas http o bucles.

                  // Toda la lógica va aquí.

                  }, error2 => {
                    console.log(error2);
                  });
            }, error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
};
```

El DataService es un archivo.ts que tendrá las llamadas http:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

private url = 'http..';

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { } 

/**
 * Devuelve los datos.
 */
public getAllDivisiones(id: string) { // --> Me voy a inventar tu llamada.
    return this.http.get<any>(this.url + '/' + id); // --> Con esta línea haces la llamada http por get.
}
```

Finalmente agrégalo al module.ts para poder usarlo.

```
import { DataService } from "./data.service";
providers: [DataService]
```